# Manipulate date in UNIX

Tags: unix, aix

I want to find a way to list all the dates of the current week in UNIX.
For example if today is 17-07-2018 then how to get dates 16-07, 18-07, 19-07 and so on for the whole week? I.e., yesterday, tomorrow, day after tomorrow etc.
I cannot use --date/d options with **date**  command as GNU is not installed. Any other commands or a user defined function to get all the dates of the given (current or any date)?

Comment: What's your definition of *week*? Monday through Friday? Sunday through Saturday?

Comment: @Jens if I'm entering Wednesday of a week (18-07) I should be able to get all dates from 16-07 till 22-07. So to answer your question it can be defined  as  Monday to Sunday

Comment: do you have `-v` option?

Comment: @Gox no that does not work either  :(

Comment: On your AIX system, does `TZ=GMT+48 date +'%d-%m'` give you the day before yesterday?

Comment: @Jens Will this command update the server  time zone permanently ? I do not want to update the environment variables for my requirement.

Comment: No, this sets TZ only for the duration of the command. It does not mess with any system settings. Use your time zone instead of GMT if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `date` recognizes TZ offsets in hours, this works for the current date:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $(date +%A) in
  (Monday)    off="  +0  -24 -48 -72 -96 -120 -144";;
  (Tuesday)   off=" +24   +0 -24 -48 -72  -96 -120";;
  (Wednesday) off=" +48  +24  +0 -24 -48  -72  -96";;
  (Thursday)  off=" +72  +48 +24  +0 -24  -48  -72";;
  (Friday)    off=" +96  +72 +48 +24  +0  -24  -48";;
  (Saturday)  off="+120  +96 +72 +48 +24   +0  -24";;
  (Sunday)    off="+144 +120 +96 +72 +48  +24   +0";;
esac
for o in $off; do
   TZ="$o" date +%d-%m
done
```

Sample run:

```
$ date
Sun Jul 15 23:13:43 CEST 2018
$ ./x.sh
09-07
10-07
11-07
12-07
13-07
14-07
15-07
```

This has no problem with leap years, under/overflow, since it uses `date`'s built-in knowledge.

PS: I just discovered that my `date` (on FreeBSD) takes these offsets from UTC, not the systems time zone; you should investigate this for AIX and if so, adjust the offsets accordingly by your local time zone offset to UTC.

Comment: TZ value in my server is EST5EDT. I suppose this is the TimeZone settings in my server,i.e., EST/EDT accordingly? Please clarify.
If I want the dates to be in EST/EDT can I update the above code as 
TZ="EST5EDT+$o" date +%d-%m

I am sorry for the basic questions  but trying to understand the TZ concepts.Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would seem, hour offsets are always relative to UTC (aka GMT). You are 5 hours east it seems, so adding (or subtracting; it's confusing) 5 to the values in `off` should work. Since you are on AIX, look here for time zone info: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-posix/index.html

Comment: I do like this solution, but localtime/UTC difference does cause problems. Also the minimalistic AIX!date is unusable for any non-trivial calculation. (Note: `%w` might be better than `%A`: it returns 0..6, localization-independent)

Answer (score 1):

Well, now I think it requires GNU!date or some actual programming language. Perl, for instance.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use POSIX;

my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst);
my ($w,$ts);

($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = gmtime();

$ENV{'TZ'}='GMT';
POSIX::tzset ();

$ts = POSIX::mktime (0, 0, 0, $mday, $mon, $year);
$ts = $ts - 24*60*60 * $wday;

for ($w= 1; $w<=7; ++$w) {
    ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =
        gmtime($ts + (24*60*60)*$w);
    printf ("%04d-%02d-%02dn", $year+1900, $mon+1, $mday);
}
```

If you save it as $HOME/bin/weekdays.pl then you can use it in your scripts:

```
set $(perl ~/bin/weekdays.pl)
echo "Monday is $1"
```