# Dates of the Current Week in Unix

Tags: unix, aix

How to get first and the last dates of the current week in ksh Unix. I cannot use 
--date/-d options with date. GNU cannot be installed.Is there any way of doing it with simple maths and not using TZ variable as well?I am using AIX.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what's your problem with `TZ`?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I am not sure if this variable needs to be handled carefully being an environmental variable..Please enlighten me with the usage of this variable

Comment: Let's go back to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51351699/manipulate-date-in-unix